# Make a templated structure to turn a pointer with any count of * to work as a &

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I've encountered a thing that got me thinking... perhaps this is an utter newbie question to ask but what I wanted to achieve is a template that would work like:

```
ForwardedReference<int****> x(somePointerWithFourStars);
int& y = x.Ref;
```

But I don't want any runtime recurrent function calls. I tried to make some partially specified structure templates, but no success yet (I will still try to achieve that goal).

My initial idea was to have two types of templates say `A<T>` and `B<T, U>` to alter one with another. The specialization of the first one would be for `T*`, and the other one for `T*, T`.

I thought to get 
`A<T*>` having a field of `B<T*, T>`, and `B<T*, T>` having `A<T>` instance.

I have failed on some compilation errors, and can't dig into that too much right now (though I will definitely look into this later), because I'm at work T_T But I'm just so eager to get an answer if this is possible to do, and how. I don't know if I will use it in the nearest future, but I like to expand my knowledge with stuff like that.

If you feel there are not enough details, please let me know - I will look at this thread from time to time.

Comment: Can you please explain **what** you are trying to do

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes why don't you make this an answer?

Comment: With optimization enabled, a function template that uses tail recursion probably will not involve runtime recursion.  And yeah, this is possible, but anything that would use it sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: ok, so first of all, without unnecessary rudeness, altough it is really tempting after seeing infinitely unconstructive comments of Martinho Fernandes, I don't want to use it anywhere - I just wanted to know if it is possible to do, and how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't want any runtime recurrent function calls

Tough shit. You can *define* the type `int&` from `int****` relatively easily with TMP, but you cannot *access* it without using recursion, because the type of each intermediate stage is different and you don't know how many intermediate stages there are. You have to use recursion to de-reference the pointer.

Comment: And what if he uses a stack to iteratively de-reference the pointer? Then he does not need recursion, right?

Comment: @Lajos: Can't be done because the types are wrong. You could only iteratively de-reference it if the types were the same.

Comment: Thanks DeadMG, that clarifies much, I will dig around that a little bit more, but thanks to your answer I am going to have an idea when to stop ;)